# Particle system/making a firework

Tags: particles

So I have to create a particle system but only make one 'firework' and have it going off in the center of the canvas. I'm just stuck on how to move the particles and have them start in the middle. Right now they're just flying everywhere.

```
`function Particle() {
this.x = Math.random() * canvas.width;
this.y = Math.random() * canvas.height;
this.vx = Math.random() * 10 - 5;
this.vy = Math.random() * 10 - 5;`
```

I keep fiddling with the numbers but it either effects the colors of the particles or only shows one particle going off. I have not worked at all with particles and what I have found online is usually in Maya or Unity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm assuming that this code is executed per particle, yes?

To center it on the canvas, you'll want the position to be (canvas width / 2, canvas height / 2), or:

```
this.x = canvas.width / 2;
this.y = canvas.height / 2;
```

This is only a single fragment,  though. To get it to cluster around that point, you might try a bell function, or more simply multiplying random by a limit:

```
this.x = (canvas.width / 2) + Math.random() * (radius * 2) - radius;
this.y = (canvas.height / 2) + Math.random() * (radius * 2) - radius;
```

The only catch about the second approach is that some particles will fly backwards, toward the firework. You can get around this by finding the relative direction:

```
Vector2 dir = ( Vector2(this.x, this.y) - Vector2(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2) ).normalized;
```

And multiplying that by a random vector (or more realistically, a power function)

```
Vector2 v = dir * Math.random();
```

-or-

```
Vector2 v = dir * Math.pow(dir.magnitude, 2);
```

Where Vector2 is any standard 2D vector class (not sure what you're using, you might want to roll your own), .magnitude is just sqrt(v.x^2 + v.y^2), and .normalized is (v.x/v.magnitude, v.y/v.magnitude).

That ought to do it.